# How to wait for number of elements to be loaded using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Let's say I'm selecting with the selector:

```
//img[@data-blabla]
```

And I want to wait for 10 elements to be loaded, not just one.

How would this be modified? I'm making a guess with the index `[9]`

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//img[@data-blabla][9]')))
```

Comment: @arundeepchohan how do I check if len() is > 9?

Comment: elem=yourwebdriver than elem.size.Should print the size of how many loaded in.

Comment: @User You need brackets `()` in the xpath, try this : `(//img[@data-blabla])[9]`

Answer (score 1):

To wait for **10** elements to load you can use the *`lambda`* function and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `>`:

  ```
  myLength = 9
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(lambda browser: len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@data-blabla]")) > int(myLength))
  ```
- Using `==`:

  ```
  myLength = 10
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(lambda browser: len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@data-blabla]")) == int(myLength))
  ```